# After the build, we are getting argon-dashboard-react/static/js/main.e8eb0f76.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build

I am using a [argon-dashboard-react](https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard-react/#/admin/index) free template for my application from creative-tim URL: https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard-react/#/admin/index, everything working fine but when I take build all the URL's come along with /argon-dashboard-react,
expected URL structure /static/js/main.e8eb0f76.chunk.js, OUT PUT : /argon-dashboard-react/static/js/main.e8eb0f76.chunk.js

Please refer my screenshot for more clarification
Local Path
[image: Local Path]
ProductionPath
[image: ProductionPath]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the issue, please delete the homepage prop from the package.json file and run again the build command (also, before that delete the old build).

and it's working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add, this also causes the build files to use the homepage for resolving %PUBLIC_URL% in the HTML files:
[image]

This may also cause the app to show blank pages when serving/deploying the web files.

@Vengat's solution fixes this issue as well.
[image]